# Allocating a new swift class object with nil property returning me nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

Am trying to create a new swift class object from objective C as well as from a swift class, in which the initializer parameter is optional.

This is the class which I am trying to initialise,

```
@objc
public class ClassStatus: NSObject {
   public private(set) var prop1: DemoClass?
   public private(set) var prop2: DemoClass2?

   public override var description: String {
       return "\(prop1)"
   }

   public init(prop: DemoClass?) {
      super.init()
      self.prop1 = prop
   }

   public convenience init(propA: DemoClass?, propB: DemoClass2) {
       self.init(prop: propA)
       self.prop2 = propB
    }
}
```

From Swift,

```
let statusObj = ClassStatus(prop: nil)
```

From Objective-C

```
ClassStatus *connState = [[ClassStatus alloc]initWithProp:nil];
```

Why the object created is nil in both the cases, instead of returning me a valid object with the intended property as nil.

EDIT::
Printing the object will give you as nil. Here, am actually trying to work with the object, and looking for the property in the object whether it is nil or valid, based on which I will proceed further. The case here is, why the object is turning up as nil instead of the creating a valid object with the property as nil.

EDIT 2: this is not a valid question, as the result for the nil is actually happening because of overriding of the description method. The object creation happens as is.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `NSLog(@"connState=%p, prop1=%p", connState, connState.prop1);` prints `connState=0x1020003f0, prop1=0x0`.

Comment: Can you try printing the object directly on the console, like do a 'po connState' . Coz that's what I am getting, and when I try to use the object, it shows as nil.

Comment: I trust NSLog more than the debugger console. Perhaps the object hasn't been created yet at the point where you try to print it in the debugger?

Comment: But, if you try to access the same object created from a swift file, it does works correctly.

Comment: The person who downrated the question, let me know how much research you want me to work on. Have pasted a working class example here. If you want me to mail a project to you, let me know

Comment: The object is not nil. What I assume is that your description method prints "nil" in that case.

Comment: It is not about printing the description. Am actually trying to work with the object, pass it to a paramter, and looking for the property to be nil, and based on that will proceed further. Here, the whole of the object is coming as nil instead of the property. Have updated the question.

Comment: I did not vote on your question, but I cannot reproduce the issue. How did you verify that `let statusObj = ClassStatus(prop: nil)` creates a `nil` object (which is technically impossible). Can you provide a *self-contained* example, a short code block which we can copy/paste into our Xcode and verify the problem? – What happens if you change the description method to `return "prop1 = \(prop1)"`

Comment: @MartinR I did not say, you have voted the question. The answer from Natarajan, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39410020/2841966 is actually the cause which is resulting in that nil object. The overriding of the description method is giving me the nil value.

Comment: The object is not nil, only the description prints "nil". And that is exactly what I said above.

Comment: @MartinR Yes. Actually, the description method is causing the issue, did not get that. My bad with that. Sorry for being irritating.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when we try to print an Object, it will print an object description from `description` property by default.

Actually you are overriding the super class(`NSObject`) property `description` with `prop1`, so whenever you are trying to print the statusObj in console or print statement, it returns nil which is coming from overriding property `description`.

So, If you remove that `description` variable from your `ClassStatus` class, you can see the actual variable in `print` or `console` statement. Otherwise you should have to initialize with `prop1` to get the none `nil` description.

Answer (score 1):

As  Martin R said it just prints the description.The ClassStatus is initiated and its not nil.I know this is not a solution but i don't have enough reputation to post comment..!! :-)

Comment: You can see the object if you comment out the below code     public override var description: String {
       return "\(prop1)"
   }

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

@objc is not required since you are subclassing NSObject.
Also, just do 'private (set)', not 'public private (set)'.

Last and more importantly, your init method must be changed into:

```
public init(prop: DemoClass?) {
    self.prop1 = prop
    super.init()
}
```

You must just initialize your members prior to calling super.init()

Comment: `prop1` is an *optional* which has `nil` as the default value, therefore calling `super.init()` first works. Otherwise the compiler would complain.

Comment: The public in public private(set) is intended, since the code is part of a framework, the property of which can be accessed outside of the framework. Not providing public, it cannot be accessed outside of the framework.  And, since the property is declared as optional, it is not necessary to initialise the property before super.init() . It is only necessary to initialise before super, if we have not declared it optional. Still, it ddnt solve the issue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here you are `overriding` default function of `NSObject` and that is currently printing `nil`

`description` is a function that prints and objects footprint.

You can check this link that how you can `override description` and take and advantage of it

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/overriding-nsobject-description-method.html